# Suggestions to create lines in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, and trying to create a function that will draw lines on the canvas. This is currently what I have and it's not working.  I may be doing unnecessary things and I need some suggestions for this code.

```
function start(){
var COUNT = 5;
for(var i = 0; i < COUNT; i++){
var row = 0;
var rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
rect.setPosition(0, row);
rect.setColor(Color.blue);

var rect1 = new Rectangle(100, 100);
rect1.setPosition(100, row);
rect1.setColor(Color.red);

var rect2 = new Rectangle(100, 100);
rect2.setPosition(200, row);
rect2.setColor(Color.blue);

var rect3 = new Rectangle(100, 100);
rect3.setPosition(300, row);
rect3.setColor(Color.red);  

add(rect);
add(rect1);
add(rect2);
add(rect3);
row + 100;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this :

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var colors = ['red','blue']

function start(){
  var COUNT = 5;
  for(var i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    for(var j = 0 ; j<4;j++){
      var rect = [10,10];
      ctx.fillStyle = colors[(i+j)%2];
      ctx.fillRect(j*10, i*10, rect[0],rect[1]);
    }
}
start();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dbo3htov/29/